# Unable to resolve my tensoflow module in react native

Tags: react-native, tensorflow

Given below is my method.

```
async recognizeImage() {

        try {
            const tfImageRecognition =  new TfImageRecognition({
                model: require('../data/graph.pb'),
                labels: require('../data/labels.txt')
            })



            const results = await tfImageRecognition.recognize({
                image: this.image
            })

            const resultText = `Name: ${results[0].name} - Confidence: ${results[0].confidence}`
            this.setState({result: resultText})

            await tfImageRecognition.close()
        } catch(err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    }
```

It gives me a error like `Unable to resolve "./graph.pb" from "app\screens\foodfind.js"` I show a similar king of question and found out two answers like create a file `rn-cli.config.js` i did it  and also i add the

```
"packagerOpts": {
      "assetExts": ["pb", "txt"]
    },
```

to the app.json file as well. But it still gives the Same error. Thats why i thought to ask the question again using the answers of the previous question as well.

[image: This is my File Architecture]